# When using QStringList to split(" "), how do I identify the last QString?

Tags: c++, qt

```
 QStringList userInfo = userFullName.split(" ");
```

I want to identify and use the last QString

Comment: use `QString last_string = userInfo.last();`

Comment: Please provide more description to your question so others can find it useful.

Comment: You need to also check that the user Info is not empty as well. E.g. QString last_string = userInfo.isEmpty() ? "" : userInfo.last();

Comment: Thank you eyllanesc, works like a charm!